# Role based rules in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a database having multiple groups - each having their own roles (admins, mods, etc..)

I have rules setup on firestore.

How do I replicate that on storage rules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it briefly, you can't without serious modifications.

Storage rules can't access Firestore documents.  So all of the relationship you have in Firestore can not be used in Storage.

You can use Firebase Auth [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to attach per-user data that can be used in both Firestore and Storage, but this means you will have to duplicate that relationship data into those claims and keep them in sync in backend code.

You can also duplicate data from Firestore into [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata) attached to files in Storage, and use that metadata in security rules to determine who can read or write individual files.

These are your only viable options without creating your own backend API endpoints that enforce security.

Comment: I already have custom claims set up. And it is like this:
claims: { claims: [groupId: ''group1", role: "admin"], ... }
Can you give an example to use claims in rules ? Is there a way to search array ?

Comment: See `request.auth.token` in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#auth

Comment: request.auth.token.claims.hasAny([
       { 'groupId': groupId, 'role': 'admin' },
       { 'groupId': groupId, 'role': 'moderator' }])
Instead of using firestore :D

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2023

Now it is possible to access Firestore and its values in storage rules.

Suspecting you have a firestore boolean field of `isAdmin` you can check if the uploading user is fulfilling this requirement:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /files/{fileId} {
      allow read, write: firestore.get(/databases/documents/users/$(request.auth.id)).isAdmin
    }
  }
}
```

You can also do more complex stuff, such as checking through lists, etc.

[See here, but don't forget to upvote ;)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#enhance_with_firestore)

Comment: I had to use `firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;` to get it to work